# Get taxonomy terms without taxonomy name

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to display the taxonomy term of a custom post type (like using `<?php the_category( ' ' ); ?>` in regular posts). The code below works but need to specify the taxonomy name, is there a way to use only the Post ID?

```
<?php

   $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'taxonomy_name' );
   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
     echo $term->name;
   }
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php print the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy_name' , ' ' ); ?>
```

You cannot get the custom taxonomy terms without taxonomy name but the above code its shorter for you.

Comment: Hi @Gazi, thanks for answer. I found a way to do it. Using this before the foreach loop: $cat = get_post_taxonomies($post);
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , $cat[1] );

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. Using "get_post_taxonomies" and selecting the array witch cat[1]

```
<?php  

$cat = get_post_taxonomies($post);
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , $cat[1] );

// Loop
if ( $terms != null ){

   foreach( $terms as $term ) {
   $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $cat[1] );

   // Print the name and URL
   echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';

   unset($term); } }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.,

```
 $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy', array("fields" => "names"));
    print_r($term_list);
```

You must use the taxonomy without taxonomy can not get term details.

Thanks you!